# Hide Facet in Design for better styling of design definition

Tags: xpages

I am currently designing my design definition to give the users of my custom controls an idea of what the xpage will look like. The only problem i have in the design panel is that even though a facet is filled with controls i can still see its name. That screws up every design coming from my design definition.

Is there a way to hide the name of the facet once controls are assigned?